# How do I get a player's username using Minecraft Forge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What I want to do is when a player picks up an item I can check the username against mine and if it matches they can keep the item and if it doesn't it gets deleted out of there inventory so only I can use the item.

I'm currently trying to do this onItemUseFist to be honest I have no idea where to start with doing this. I already have the item I want to do this to. I just don't know how to do that. I think xComp does something like this with his glasses in Mystcraft.

Thanks in advance,

Josh

Comment: @Judge2020 Thanks for the reply but I have already tried that and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/mods-discussion/1399911-how-do-i-get-a-players-username-with-forge,

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.username.equals("username")
```

works. You can put that as the arguments of an `if`. `then` statement then an `else` statement to do what you want to happen if it doesn't match your username. You could also invert the if statement with a `!` before the first M then have the code run in the `then` statement.

Answer (score -1):

In the code of Forge for 1.12 I found:

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.getName()
```

Comment: Can you expand on this to cover how OP might use it to get player names?